# Exporting layer symbology using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, symbology, export, qml

I need to save the symbology of several layers and I would like to do it with a PyQGIS-3 script.

I think I have to use the [QgsMapLayerStyle](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Map/QgsMapLayerStyle.html?highlight=write%20qml) class but I don't understand what is a [QDocument](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/tests/src/python/test_qgsvectorlayer.py#L2396) and how to use this class

```py
niv1 = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('exempleNiveau1_UniteDiagnostic_CMH_valeur normalise')[0]
doc = QDomDocument("testdoc") # path to qml/xml document to create ?
elem = doc.createElement("maplayer") # layer with the symbology to save ? Vector layer is not supported
niv1.writeXml(elem, doc, QgsReadWriteContext())

doc = QDomDocument("C:/Users/Juliette/Documents/CRECQ/CartesIndicateurs/Layers/testdoc")
elem = doc.createElement("exempleNiveau1_UniteDiagnostic_CMH_valeur normalise")
niv1.writeXml(elem, doc, QgsReadWriteContext())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the [`saveNamedStyle`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapLayer.html#aca5aecf2287023a11a925e928a7d225e) function:

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
bckup_fileName = bckupFolder + layer.name() + ".qml"
layer.saveNamedStyle(bckup_fileName)
```